# Update One Table From Another Having No Common Condition

Tags: sql-server

I need to update one table from another but the main issue is that these two tables don't have any common condition that can be used in either a Join or Where clause.
I have one table name: **Region**. It has following columns: RegionId (PK), RegionNo, and GlobalLocationId (FK). Second table: **GlobalLocation**. It has following columns: GlobalLocationId (PK) and GlobalLocationGuid. 
 This is the data stored in both tables. 
[image] 
I need to update **Region.GlobalLocationId** from **GlobalLocation.GlobalLocationId**.

I tried this approach but it didn't work.

```
        WITH CTE
        AS (SELECT R.GlobalLocationId AS tgt_gID,
                G.GlobalLocationId AS source_gID
         FROM   Zion.Region R
                LEFT JOIN Zion.GlobalLocation G
                  ON R.GlobalLocationId = G.GlobalLocationId)
        UPDATE CTE
        SET tgt_gID = source_gID;
```

I don't know what else to try in order to update my **Region** Table.

Comment: See: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281), specifically about providing sample data and _expected results_.

Comment: @ErikDarling what part of the question is not clear to you?

Comment: Heh, what part of my comment isn't clear to you?

Comment: Based on the schema of your tables, there's no clear way to discern how the rows in one table relate to the other table. If you can explain in words which row from `Region` relates to `GlobalRegion`, and why / how they relate, then likely there's a programmatic solution that we can offer. But right now, as your question is written, it's not clear what you even want to do logically (putting the code to accomplish it aside).